# How to add multiple images layers in OpenFramework

Tags: openframeworks

Is it possible add multiple images layers
 as a single object so that is we can apply 
various filter on layered images;I want to rotate group of images

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for here, it would help if you clearly worded your question!

However, in openFrameworks, this is the class you'll firstly want to manage pictures in a easy manner:
http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofImage.html

For easy filters you can use the below or you can define your own.
https://github.com/Ahbee/ofxCoreImageFilters

To have multiple image layers then I presume you'll want to look into vectors. Perhaps write a layer class that has a picture and a vector of filters, and then push multiple layer objects into a vector in the ofApp class.

Best, Leon

Comment: Thanks Leon , Actually I want to  rotate and translate  container and image inside container; just like in photoshop; can we use ofxcvcolorImage to do such functionality ?

Comment: Check out the ofxCvColorImage reference (find it here: http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/ofxOpenCv/ofxCvColorImage.html)

It is used for getting pixel values in video or pictures and handling pictures in openFrameworks so it's certainly an option. I'd suggest checking out the library ofImage - It's part of openFrameworks and it may be more suited to your needs. 

http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofImage.html

After declaring your image you can easily load one like so. Then it's up to you to transform your image as you need!

`myImage.loadImage("icon.gif");`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should develop a data structure to handle groups of images.

For example, a BaseGraphics is the abstract class, which has position, rotation, scale and children. Concrete classes could be ImageGraphics, VideoGraphics, etc.

BaseGraphics would contains a list of child BaseGraphics. The position, rotation and scale of each child is respective of the parent BaseGraphics. Therefore, if an instance rotates, all its descendants would be rotated accordingly.

The drawing function would be like this:

```
BaseGraphics::draw() {
    ofPushMatrix()
    ofTranslate(), ofScale(), ofRotate();
    drawElement();
    foreach (child) {
        child.draw ();
    }
    ofPopMatrix();
}
```